# C# cинхронизация потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность, синхронизация

Возникла проблема с синхронизацией потоков.
Общая схема упрощенно в следующем.
Есть ПК к которому подключены два устройства через 2 `Com`-порта.
Из каждого устройства через свой порт в отдельном потоке читаются переменные  (один порт - один поток, код одинаковый):

```
поток 1 - устройство 1 - переменные Val1, Val2

поток 2 - устройство 2 - переменные Val3, Val4

Третий поток - UI, читает Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4.
```

Вопрос:
Как обеспечить запрет чтения на время обновления переменной, но чтобы при этом поток 1 не блокировал поток 2.

Если сделать так в потоках 1 и 2:

```
   if (port==1)
       PortValues=...
   else
       PortValues=...
   lock (thisLock)  
    {  
       //чтение из Com-порта ....
       foreach(var v in PortValues)
           v.Val = ReadFromComPort(port, v.Name);
    }
```

то они, по-идее, будут блокировать друг-друга, но этого не нужно, т.к. они обновляют разные переменные.
Как этого избежать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А чем вам не нравится обыкновенный `lock`?

Например, объявляем объекты для блокировки:

```
object port1lock = new object();
object port2lock = new object();
```

В потоке №1:

```
var (v1, v2) = readValues();
lock (port1lock)
    (Val1, Val2) = (v1, v2);
```

В потоке №2:

```
var (v3, v4) = readValues();
lock (port2lock)
    (Val3, Val4) = (v3, v4);
```

И в UI-потоке:

```
// объявить переменные v1, v2, v3, v4 ...
lock (port1lock) lock (port2lock)
    (v1, v2, v3, v4) = (Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4)
```

---

С другой стороны, холостое чтение в UI-потоке — не лучшая идея. Поэтому, возможно, вам стоит при изменении значений, прочитанных из портов, отправлять из рабочих потоков в UI-поток event, в котором вы будете передавать новые значения. Таким образом у вас разделяемые переменные совсем уйдут, а с ними и необходимость блокировки.

Comment: тоже так подумал, но посчитал, что есть способ более оптимальный. Кстати, а он есть ?

Comment: @Lolidze: Как раз дописал ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Наверно как то так и придется делать. С эвентами не подходит, т.к. UI не совсем UI, а wcf сервис. И переменных не 2, а несколько сотен. На опрос устройств через Modbus rtu требуется время. Написал так, пытаясь упростить вопрос. Идея была в том, что бы блокировать не на время процесса опроса, а запрещать сервису читать конкретную переменную во время именно ЕЁ обновления. Иначе отзывчивость сервиса стремится к нулю.

Comment: @micom: Ну идея в том, что вы читаете в локальные переменные, а потом уж вытесняете их под блокировкой куда надо.